# Pyinstaller OneDir exe of project with multiple support .py files

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, executable

I'm running this command from the directory of my project :

```
pyinstaller --onedir -w Main.py Support1.py Support2.py Support3.py
```

For more context, Support1.py imports Support2.py and Support3.py as modules and Main.py imports Support1.py.

It successfully builds the executable, and it does startup much faster than the onefile version, however it seems that the import of Support1.py by the main doesn't work.
Main.py contains a simple Tk interface that is displayed by the exe without issue, but as soon as I press the button that calls a function defined in Support1.py nothing happens.

I tried copying the Support.py files in the executable directory to no effect.

Are there options I should take into account when creating the executable ?

What perplexes me is that the onefile executable works fine once built, but I want the onedir to let my coworkers who don't have python installed use the app as well.

Thank you in advance for any help with this

Comment: does the import of the other modules (support 2,3) work?

Answer (score 0):

If it is an import problem you could put all of your support files are in a subdirectory. Then add the dirs with `--paths dir1:dir2:dir3` to pyinstaller.